# Angular, how to generate component inside secondary entry point?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, package.json, entry-point

How to use `angular-cli` commands to generate `components`, `modules` etc inside secondary entry points.

Fileing:

```
my_package
├── src
|   ├── public_api.ts
|   └── *.ts
├── ng-package.json
├── package.json
└── testing
    ├── src
    |   ├── public_api.ts
    |   └── *.ts
    └── package.json
```

In my case, how to generate component inside `my-package/testing/src/components`

Answer (score -1):

I usually go with my terminal there with `cd` so `cd my-package/testing/src/components`.

But if you are in root module you can also create component from there like `ng g c my-package/testing/src/components/NameOfYourNewComponent`.

To test this behaviour you can use `--dry-run` flag so no changes are made but you'll see what and where is generated.